# Listview highlight moves very slowly

Tags: android, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have implemented a simple QML application using model-view-delegate paradigm. In my application I use `highlight` property to underline the currently selected item of my `ListView`. Selection works fine but when I click items which are far away the highlighting moves quite slowly.

Consider the following example:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("List test")
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 20

        delegate: Rectangle {
            border.color: "steelblue"
            color: Qt.lighter(border.color)
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 20

            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; z: 2; text: index + 1 }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: view.currentIndex = index
            }
        }

        highlight: Rectangle {
            border.color: "yellow"
            border.width: 3
            color: "transparent"
            height: 20
            width: ListView.view.width
            z: Infinity
        }
    }
}
```

If you select the last element, the highlighting moves over all the other items before arriving to the selected one. That's not the behaviour I expect. How can I move the highlighting directly to the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you have experienced it's the intended one, according to the documentation of [`highlightFollowsCurrentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightFollowsCurrentItem-prop):

> This property holds whether the highlight is **managed by the view**.
>
> **If this property is true (the default value), the highlight is moved smoothly to follow the current item**. Otherwise, the highlight is not moved by the view, and any movement must be implemented by the highlight.

The highlight animation is controlled by [`highlightMoveDuration`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightMoveDuration-prop) and [`highlightMoveVelocity`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightMoveVelocity-prop) properties. The velocity is set to `400 pixels/second`, a value that could correspond to a long-running animation on a high-density device with a long view.

You can solve the issue in two different ways:

- by fine tuning the above mentioned properties (by e.g. setting a very small `highlightMoveDuration` or an high `highlightMoveVelocity`)
- by setting `highlightFollowsCurrentItem` to `false` and directly manage the highlighting animation

In the second case you discard the animation and directly bind the highlighting `y` position with `y` of the currently selected delegate. This way, the highlighting is instantaneously moved to the selected delegate, like in the example below:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("List test")
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 20

        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false    // force discarding default animation

        delegate: Rectangle {
            border.color: "steelblue"
            color: Qt.lighter(border.color)
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 20

            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; z: 2; text: index + 1 }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: view.currentIndex = index
            }
        }

        highlight: Rectangle {
            border.color: "yellow"
            border.width: 3
            color: "transparent"
            height: 20
            width: ListView.view.width
            y:  view.currentItem.y      // highlighting direct binding to selected item!
            z: Infinity
        }
    }
}
```